# using a tag in when specifying an element class

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am using djangos temlpate language to specify whether an elements class is active or not.

Here is my html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="{% block isRecent %}{% endblock %}">
        <a href="/">Recent Feedback</a>
    </li>
    <li class="{% block isAll %}{% endblock %}">
        <a href="/allFeedback">All Feedback</a>
    </li>
    <li class="{% block isIndividual %}{% endblock %}">
        <a href="/individualFeedback">Individual Feedback</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this template is then inherited, and I will specify the class of each `<li>` like so:

```
{% block isRecent %}active{% endblock %}
```

This works fine, however I can also see actual text "active" in my bowser ..

[image: example of the issue]

Looking at the source code, there doesn't seem to be any 'rogue' text anywhere ..

```
<div class="navbarWrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="/">Recent Feedback</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/allFeedback">All Feedback</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/individualFeedback">Individual Feedback</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is rather annoying -_-

Have I made a mistake somewhere ? Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Nothing yet? The code seems to be fine, try to do a full refresh with Ctrl+F5

Comment: Post the template that inherits from that one please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the {% block isRecent %} tag is defined **outside** of the {% block content %} tag, but in the template that inherits this template I used the {% block isRecent %} tag **inside** the {% block content %} tag. Moving it to outside the {% block content %} tag resolved the issue.